# Vue 3 - template ref with computed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How may I focus on this simple input example?
Should I create one more variable `const nameRef = ref(null)` or there is more beauty way to resolve this?

```
 <template>
    <input ref="name" :value="name" />
 </template>
    
 <script>
    import {ref, computed} from 'vue';
    export default {
      props: ['name'],
      setup(props) {
        const name = computed(() => someTextPrepare(props.name));
    
        // how can I do name.value.focus() for example?
    
        return { name }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: tried `this.$refs.name.focus()`?

Comment: no, I use composition api

Comment: All you need is in the docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#watching-template-refs

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the `name` value and ref in reactive property :

```
 <template>
    <input :ref="theName.ref" :value="theName.value" />
 </template>
    
 <script>
    import {ref, computed,reactive} from 'vue';
    export default {
      props: ['name'],
      setup(props) {
        const theName=reactive({
                 value:computed(() => someTextPrepare(props.name)),
                 ref: ref(null)
         })
   
        return { theName }
      }
    }
</script>
```